# Prolog Compilation Error "Undefined reference to predicate"

Tags: prolog

We have just started working on Prolog in one of my programming classes. I am getting a few errors and I am not completely sure on  what is causing them. This is homework so I am not expecting any written out answers, but any hints would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
/* Database for family. It consists of facts and rules. */

/* Facts */
male(mark).

/* Question 1.1 */
male(tom).
male(eric).
male(josh). 
male(austin).

/* Question 1.1 */      
female(jen).
female(beth).
female(lisa).
female(alice).
female(alex).

father_of(mark, beth). /* mark is the father of beth */

/* Question 1.1
father_of(josh, eric).
father_of(eric, mark).
father_of(eric, jen).
father_of(austin, alice).

mother_of(jen, tom). /* jen is the mother of tom */

/* Question 1.1
mother_of(lisa, eric).
mother_of(alex, alice).
mother_of(alice, jen).
mother_of(alice, mark).

/* Rules */

is_male(X) :-
male(X);
father_of(X, _).

/* Question 1.2 */
is_female(X) :-
    female(X);
    mother_of(X, _).

/* Question 1.3 */
grandfather_of(X, Z) :-
  father_of(X, Y), 
  (mother_of(Y, Z); father_of(Y, Z)).


grandmother_of(X, Z) :- 
    mother_of(X, Y), 
    (mother_of(Y, Z); father_of(Y, Z)).
```

The errors I am receiving:
/tmp/gplc0GI9tg.o: In function `Lpred7_1':

(.text+0x2d1): undefined reference to `predicate(mother_of/2)'
/tmp/gplc0GI9tg.o: In function`predicate(grandfather_of/2)':

(.text+0x35d): undefined reference to `predicate(mother_of/2)'
/tmp/gplc0GI9tg.o: In function`predicate(grandmother_of/2)':

(.text+0x3a8): undefined reference to `predicate(mother_of/2)'
/tmp/gplc0GI9tg.o: In function`predicate(grandmother_of/2)':

(.text+0x3ed): undefined reference to `predicate(mother_of/2)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
compilation failed

Comment: Check where your comments begin and end...

Comment: @Stevem Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code snippet, the following lines are spurious:

```
/* Question 1.1
father_of(josh, eric).
```

Same thing, not much later:

```
/* Question 1.1
mother_of(lisa, eric).
```

I assume you wanted to end the respective comments before writing down the following facts.

**Best practise:** Use end-of-line comments (starting with `%`) whenever they suffice.